# When a child of a parent has a condition(checked) target the parent sibling

Tags: css

When a child of a parent has a condition(checked) target the parent sibling.

I tried the following code but it is not working, because it goes after the child sibling:

```css
.content {
  top:      0px;
  width:      75%;
  max-width: 300px;
  background: $white;
  z-index: 10;
  box-shadow: 5px 0 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.1);
  padding-top: 20px;
   transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  }


.toggle > input[type='checkbox']:checked ~ .content:first-of-type{
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="toggle">
  <input type="checkbox" id="toggle">
  <i>dsaosame cicon and text</>
</div>

<div class="content">
  <ul>
    <li>aaa</li>
    <li>dsadsads</li>
   </ul>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <ul>
    <li>aaa</li>
    <li>dsadsads</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: This will not work as CSS does not have the ability to traverse back up the DOM tree. You would either have to use JavaScript or amend the DOM layout.

Comment: not sure why repeating the same question:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54669723/show-hide-elements-based-on-a-checkbox-input-state .. the duplicate is the same, what is not clear there? you can still edit and ping the duplicate closer